# css animation issue with steps

Tags: css, css-animations

I would like to ask if it's any way to make css animation bit smoother ? because now I got issue that on each steps my animation making "breaks" and it's not that nice smooth animation. As you can se here:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes rocketStart {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  5% {
    transform: translate(0, 20px) rotate(20deg);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translate(-10px, 40px) rotate(25deg);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(-20px, 60px) rotate(40deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate(-45px, 80px) rotate(55deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(-85px, 105px) rotate(68deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-195px, 135px) rotate(77deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-400px, 300px);
  }
}
.rocket-move-one {
  -webkit-animation-name: rocketStart;
  animation-name: rocketStart;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.rocket {
  position: absolute;
  width: 45px;
  height: 92px;
  left: 485px;
  top: -50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%; height:600px; position;relative;">
  <div class="rocket-move-one rocket"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: With a keyframe definition as specific and staggered as that, your best bet would be to use `animation-timing-function: linear`. Default value is `ease` and so you will see slower starts, quicker middle portion and slower ends *between each keyframes*.

Comment: Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/L53pzkwc/) maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.rocket-move-one {
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `animation-timing-function: linear;` to get even animation speed.

You might need to tweak the key frames something like below example for smoother transition.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes rocketStart {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-195px, 135px) rotate(77deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-400px, 300px) rotate(0deg);
  }
}
.rocket-move-one {
  -webkit-animation-name: rocketStart;
  animation-name: rocketStart;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.rocket {
  position: absolute;
  width: 45px;
  height: 92px;
  left: 485px;
  top: -50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%; height:600px; position;relative;">
  <div class="rocket-move-one rocket"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
-webkit-transition:all 1s ease;
```

and mention `animation-timing-function`